# Objective C syntax help - literals

Tags: objective-c, syntax, literals

Need some help with the following objective-c syntax:

```
[error.userInfo[FBErrorParsedJSONResponseKey][@"body"][@"error"][@"type"] isEqualToString:@"OAuthException"]
```

Whats going on here? How are body,error and type literals being used?

Here's the complete block call:

```
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // handle successful response
    } else if ([error.userInfo[FBErrorParsedJSONResponseKey][@"body"][@"error"][@"type"] isEqualToString:@"OAuthException"]) { 
        NSLog(@"The facebook session was invalidated");
        [self logoutButtonTouchHandler:nil];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Some other error: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

I have also seen syntax like

```
self.userProfile = [PFUser currentUser][@"profile"];
```

where `userProfile` is an `NSDictionary` and `[PFUser currentUser]` returns `PFUser`.
How does `[PFUser][@"profile]` initialize a dictionary?

Comment: @H2CO3: I guess you are mistaken the "thanks" wasn't my edit.

Comment: @Gayu Then why is "Thanks" in green in the diff under your edit?

Comment: @Gayu [This](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15676618/revisions) says it was yours.

Comment: @h2CO3 i have had this before, if you start editing while another person is, it will revert who evers changes happened first, because while you are editing, the new changes dont come through for the person submitting edits second. since your edits were ~1 min apart this is most likely what happened

Comment: @Fonix That's definitely possible. Should I file a bug on Meta? All this shall not be happening, false evidence is wrong.

Comment: So does the following code accessing nested dictionaries?      [error.userInfo[FBErrorParsedJSONResponseKey][@"body"][@"error"][@"type"] isEqualToString:@"OAuthException"]